# Why is numpy.exp on a complex meshgrid array giving the wrong real part?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, complex-numbers

I have a nested array of complex numbers,

```
xi:

 [[[ 2.51325641-2.34963293j  2.17949212-1.57079633j  2.51325641-0.79195972j]
  [ 2.15322703+3.14159265j  0.00000000+1.57079633j  2.15322703+0.j        ]
  [ 2.51325641+2.34963293j  2.17949212+1.57079633j  2.51325641+0.79195972j]]

 [[ 2.44651048-2.3486959j   2.11452586-1.57079633j  2.44651048-0.79289676j]
  [ 2.08450333+3.14159265j  0.00000000+1.57079633j  2.08450333+0.j        ]
  [ 2.44651048+2.3486959j   2.11452586+1.57079633j  2.44651048+0.79289676j]]]
```

and taking numpy.exp gives me the following:

```
np.exp(xi):

 [[[ -8.67181418e+00 -8.78636871e+00j   5.41404995e-16 -8.84181457e+00j
     8.67181418e+00 -8.78636871e+00j]
  [ -8.61260674e+00 +1.05474013e-15j   6.12323400e-17 +1.00000000e+00j
     8.61260674e+00 +0.00000000e+00j]
  [ -8.67181418e+00 +8.78636871e+00j   5.41404995e-16 +8.84181457e+00j
     8.67181418e+00 +8.78636871e+00j]]

 [[ -8.10419460e+00 -8.22665532e+00j   5.07350124e-16 -8.28565631e+00j
     8.10419460e+00 -8.22665532e+00j]
  [ -8.04059693e+00 +9.84689130e-16j   6.12323400e-17 +1.00000000e+00j
     8.04059693e+00 +0.00000000e+00j]
  [ -8.10419460e+00 +8.22665532e+00j   5.07350124e-16 +8.28565631e+00j
     8.10419460e+00 +8.22665532e+00j]]]
```

However the real parts of some of the elements are incorrect when I check them individually, e.g. the 2nd column of the first row of the first nested array:

```
In [1]: np.exp(2.17949212-1.57079633j)
Out[1]: (-2.833893031963725e-08-8.8418145374224597j)
```

but others are fine (e.g. array 1 row 1 column 1).

```
In [2]: np.exp(2.51325641-2.34963293j)
Out[2]: (-8.671814171261488-8.7863687332566318j)
```

This makes no sense to me, because the numpy.exp documentation seems to imply that e^(a+ib) is calculated as e^a*(cos(b) + i sin(b)), so I don't see how the imaginary part can be correct while the real part is not.

Is it possible to make numpy.exp work consistently for my array?

**EDIT:**

It's been pointed out that defining xi as above does give the correct result with np.exp; it also works in my python environment when I define it as a standalone array of the values above. However, np.exp(xi) still doesn't seem to work correctly with the way I've generated xi:

```
d = np.array([0.91651514, 0.9797959])

spacing = 3
limit = 4
x = np.linspace(-limit, limit,spacing)
y = np.linspace(-limit,limit,spacing)
X, Y = np.meshgrid(x, y)
def z(x,y):
    return x + 1j * y
z = z(X, Y)

xi = []
for i in range(len(d)):
    xxi = np.arccosh(z/d[i])
    xi.append(xxi)
xi = np.asarray(xi)
```

Is there something about the way I've created xi that makes it work strangely with numpy.exp?

Comment: is this a 3D tensor? because it's 3x3x2.

Comment: @HadiFarah yup it's a shape (2,3,3) array. does np.exp not work on those?

Comment: I am testing it now to be sure, I never tried on anything above 2D, just wanted to make sure to get it right.

Comment: it computes the correct results on mine as well. Try to look if you are passing something incorrectly.

Comment: Up to rounding error, 5.41404995e-16 and -2.833893031963725e-08 are both 0.

Comment: @HadiFarah I can't think of anything I'm doing wrong, unless arrays made using np.meshgrid passes things differently to np.exp? I've edited the question to show how I've made xi, which might be the problem (except I don't see why it would be or how to fix it)

Comment: I think it is as @user2357112 said, it is only a rounding errors because your error are all values that tend towards zero. This is very possible because you are doing exponent of a trigonometric function of a fraction, while we during testing copy the values of `xi` as `2.51325641-2.34963293j ...` inside your machine it is probably `2.51325641.... - 2.34963293...j  ...` some more values that are not printed that would only show up for when an a mathematical operation is suppose to tend to zero.

Comment: If I do `print(xi[0][0][0])` and `print('%.30f' % xi[0][0][0])` >> `2.513256407818519` `2.513256407818519111430077828118`

Comment: @HadiFarah ah okay i think you're right! taking `np.exp(2.179492122140042731359699246241-1.570796326794896557998981734272j)` does give me `5.41404995e-16 -8.84181457e+00j`, so it makes sense now :) thanks for the explanation!

Answer (score 0):

According to my results, numpy seems to indeed compute the correct results:

Traceback from my console:

```
import numpy as np

xi = np.array([[
  [2.51325641-2.34963293j,  2.17949212-1.57079633j,  2.51325641-0.79195972j],
  [ 2.15322703+3.14159265j,  0.00000000+1.57079633j,  2.15322703+0.j        ],
  [ 2.51325641+2.34963293j,  2.17949212+1.57079633j , 2.51325641+0.79195972j]],

 [[ 2.44651048-2.3486959j ,  2.11452586-1.57079633j , 2.44651048-0.79289676j],
  [ 2.08450333+3.14159265j , 0.00000000+1.57079633j , 2.08450333+0.j        ],
  [ 2.44651048+2.3486959j ,  2.11452586+1.57079633j , 2.44651048+0.79289676j]]])



xi
Out[7]: 
array([[[2.51325641-2.34963293j, 2.17949212-1.57079633j,
         2.51325641-0.79195972j],
        [2.15322703+3.14159265j, 0.        +1.57079633j,
         2.15322703+0.j        ],
        [2.51325641+2.34963293j, 2.17949212+1.57079633j,
         2.51325641+0.79195972j]],

       [[2.44651048-2.3486959j , 2.11452586-1.57079633j,
         2.44651048-0.79289676j],
        [2.08450333+3.14159265j, 0.        +1.57079633j,
         2.08450333+0.j        ],
        [2.44651048+2.3486959j , 2.11452586+1.57079633j,
         2.44651048+0.79289676j]]])

np.exp(xi)
Out[8]: 
array([[[-8.67181417e+00-8.78636873e+00j,
         -2.83389303e-08-8.84181454e+00j,
          8.67181420e+00-8.78636870e+00j],
        [-8.61260674e+00+3.09174756e-08j,
         -3.20510345e-09+1.00000000e+00j,
          8.61260674e+00+0.00000000e+00j],
        [-8.67181417e+00+8.78636873e+00j,
         -2.83389303e-08+8.84181454e+00j,
          8.67181420e+00+8.78636870e+00j]],

       [[-8.10419466e+00-8.22665531e+00j,
         -2.65563855e-08-8.28565627e+00j,
          8.10419461e+00-8.22665536e+00j],
        [-8.04059697e+00+2.88640789e-08j,
         -3.20510345e-09+1.00000000e+00j,
          8.04059697e+00+0.00000000e+00j],
        [-8.10419466e+00+8.22665531e+00j,
         -2.65563855e-08+8.28565627e+00j,
          8.10419461e+00+8.22665536e+00j]]])

np.exp(2.17949212-1.57079633j)
Out[9]: (-2.833893031963725e-08-8.84181453742246j)
```

I am using Python 3.6.5 (Anaconda Python), with NumPy version 1.14.3. Have you tried verifying your results on another machine/other python instance?

Comment: good idea! I just updated both anaconda and numpy to check - but it still doesn't work when I run my entire code (in qtconsole)... but if I define xi on its own the standalone array does give me the correct np.exp(xi). I think @HadiFarah might be right that I'm passing something incorrectly, I'll give it another look!